# Combine physical path and virtual path outside ASP.NET

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to convert a virtual file path to a physical file path in a windows service.

I know what the physical path is for the virtual directory, so I have the following function that works, but feels like a fudge:

```
public static string GetPhysicalPathFromVirtual(string rootPath, string virtualPath)
{
    int trailingSlash = virtualPath.IndexOf('/', 1) + 1;
    int length = virtualPath.Length - trailingSlash;
    string stripped = virtualPath.Substring(trailingSlash, length);
    stripped = stripped.Replace(@"/", @"\");
    return Path.Combine(rootPath, stripped);
}
```

The following example:

```
string test = FileHelper.GetPhysicalPathFromVirtual(@"T:\generateddocuments\output\", @"/virtualroot/folder/myfile.pdf");
```

Returns: T:\generateddocuments\output\folder\myfile.pdf

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) may be of help for your task.

Please note that using relative paths in services can expose a huge security hole so you should be very defensive when you code them.

Here's what I came up with:

```
public static string GetPhysicalPathFromVirtual(string rootPath, string virtualPath)
{
    const string mandatoryVirtualPrefix = "/virtualroot/";

    if (!virtualPath.StartsWith(mandatoryVirtualPrefix))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(virtualPath, string.Format("Virtual '{0}' path must start with mandatory prefix '{1}'", virtualPath, mandatoryVirtualPrefix));

    var relativePath = virtualPath.Substring(mandatoryVirtualPrefix.Length);

    var rootUri = new Uri(rootPath, UriKind.Absolute);
    var relativeUri = new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative);

    var absoluteUri = new Uri(rootUri, relativeUri);

    if (!rootUri.IsBaseOf(absoluteUri))
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(virtualPath, string.Format("Virtual path '{0}' can't be outside of root '{1}'", virtualPath, rootPath));

    return absoluteUri.LocalPath;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you need to know the virtual root. In my case, I don't, and I don't want to pass it into the method either. That's why I search for the first folder path, and then remove it. Maybe the Uri class might help though. I'll try it out.

Comment: If you don't want to pass it, where do you want to get it from? Is it the same folder where exe is run from?

Comment: This is an old question, which I have just reviewed. Your code wasn't quite right because it wasn't returning a local file path as per my question. It needs to return absoluteUri.LocalPath. Edited your answer and awarded answer to you. :)